# Laravel Auth Middleware not Working for POST Route

Tags: php, laravel, post, middleware, laravel-middleware

I have a simple form in my site and I want to check if the user is currently logged in before he can post the form. I have put auth middleware in the post route...

```
Route::post('test','SellController@test_mid')->middleware('auth');
```

My auth middleware...

```
<?php

public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Here **'login'** redirects to my login page.

The problem is after I hit the login button, the error is...

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219: 
>   at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in
>   RouteCollection.php line 206

Form...

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>"/test")) }}=
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
{{ Form::close() }}
```

But if I set the auth middleware on a **GET** route, it works fine. In case of a **GET**, if I am logged out, it leads me to the login page. After I provide login credentials and hit the login button it leads me to the desired **GET** route.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your view form uses POST method.

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'/test', 'method'=>'post'))}}
```

Please note that `$guard` variable is NULL by default unless specified. See your `/config/auth.php` configuration for available guards.

```
Route::post('test', 'SellController@test_mid')->middleware('auth:web');
```

Comment: 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

Comment: Actually the guard is web by default. Are you sure you're making POST request `/test` route? Append your HTML view to the question.

Comment: I have added it.please check.

Comment: Make sure you pass proper method in the form. See my answer above.

Comment: I explained it.MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 206

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135775/discussion-between-chris-cynarski-and-asm-arman).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is an old story, but it seems that you have not the answer yet. I suggest using middleware inside your controller instead of routes.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class YourController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function yourFunction(Request $request){
      // your action
    }
}
```

It works fine for me, either GET or POST method.